# SQL to fetch Latest record of each item from the table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

Im trying to query the database to fetch latest record for each stock using `max(Created_at)` and grouping by `stockId` but with that it brings the **first** `id` of each item with its **last** `Created_at`.

How can i get it to bring the latest records collectively? Please help out.
My query is as follows :

```
SELECT a.id as A_id, b.id as B_id, max(b.Created_at) AS Created_at 
  FROM beta b 
 INNER JOIN alpha a ON b.a_id = a.id 
 GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @ Strawberry. I hope thats what you meant

Comment: @ Barbaros Ozhan. 8+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use analytic functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT A_id, B_id , Created_at
  FROM
  (
   SELECT a.id as A_id, b.id as B_id , b.Created_at,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.Created_at DESC) as rn
     FROM beta b 
     JOIN alpha a ON b.a_id = a.id 
  ) q
  WHERE rn = 1
```

where your records are grouped by stockID(`a.id`) and pick the **latest** after ordering by `created_at` column descendingly. If ties(equal `created_at` values for each grouped `stockId`) matters and all satisfying results should be included in the result set, then replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `DENSE_RANK()`.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand u need like this

```
declare @item table
(
itemid int
,itemname varchar(100)
)
insert into @item
values(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')

declare @stock table
(
itemid int
,stockid int
,updatedate datetime
)
insert into @stock
values(1,1,'2020-08-04 13:11'),(1,1,'2020-08-04 14:11')
      ,(1,2,'2020-08-04 15:11'),(1,2,'2020-08-04 14:11') 


select * from @item a
 inner join
(select stockid,itemid,max(updatedate)lastupdatedate from @stock
group by stockid,itemid
)b on a.itemid=b.itemid
```